# How to replace directory path in each row of a column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dataframe which has a filename column that looks like this:

```
Filename
/var/www/html/projects/Bundesliga/Match1/STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00001.jpg
/var/www/html/projects/Bundesliga/Match1/STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00001.jpg
```

From the Filename column I want to replace the directory name with a new destination directory name.

```
dst = "/home/mycomp/Images'
```

I have tried the following:

```
df['Filename'] = df['Filename'].str.replace(os.path.dirname(df['Filename']), dst)
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 129, in dirname
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df['Filename'] = df['Filename'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(os.path.dirname(x), dst))
```

Comment: This works but is inefficient if you have the same path across rows (as here). For larger dataframes, I suggest you calculate the path(s) to replace separately.

Comment: What do you think of converting to category first ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `os.path.dirname(df['Filename'])`: you are passing a `Series` here where it expects a `str`. What you can do is `filenames = df['Filename'].str.split('/').str[-1]` to get the filename without the directory and then `dst + '/' + filenames` to get the new paths. Better to define `dst = '"/home/mycomp/Images/'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using regular expression.

```
import os, re

dst = r'/home/mycomp/Images'

paths = '|'.join([re.escape(s) for s in set(df['Filename'].map(os.path.dirname))])

df['Filename'] = df['Filename'].str.replace(paths, dst)

#                                             Filename
# 0  /home/mycomp/Images/STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200...
# 1  /home/mycomp/Images/STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200...
```

**Explanation**

- Extract all directories, escape special characters, and combine into a single string separated by `|` [regex or]. This ensures *all* paths in the series are replaced.
- Use `os.path.dirname` to extract the correct path across platforms.
- Use `pd.Series.str.replace` with regex to replace all paths with `dst` input.